# admin-ajax.php error 500 on windows

Tags: php, iis

Got a question about admin-ajax.php. I have a wordpress site that we got developed and a form that uses this php file. this form uses AJAX and PHP to submit to the  API that we use. a applyform-page-form.php file contains the Jquery and AJAX calls. These calls utilize a custom plugin to facilitate the XML process. All of the standard WordPress add_action(); calls are processed in this plugin. The site was developed on a Linux hosting panel (hostgator) and was working great. Due to PCI compliancy issues we needed to migrate the site to a Windows IIS host. Once we moved to this host, we get an error 500 with admin-ajax.php. I am stumped on what is causing this error. I checked permissions on the folder and they are fine. The server setup seems ok, we are using the same version of PHP on the windows server, Curl is installed, Not getting any errors in the iis server logs, php server logs are pretty much useless as well.

Question is does anyone know if there are any issues with admin-ajax.php on an IIS server? I have googled for a couple days and nothing about IIS, just mainly Apache and all the answers were basically "get a new host".

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing is that Wordpress use a file call .HTACCESS where it maps the routes for events and request, so, what is hapend here is that you call admin-ajax.php from somewhere that has no "ROUTE", and that is why you have an error 500, but is just because the wordpress is trying to find something that it cand reach.

Try to use the full path to this file.